# How to select all elements between two same elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in a div-container I want to select and group all headlines with its content until the next headline. These blocks should have a different background-color.

This is what I got in my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <ul></ul>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

And what I need is this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="xy">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="xy">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="xy">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using nextUntil() but it didn't work for me so far.

I would appreciate any help.

Best,
Robin

Comment: Can you show us the JavaScript you've written up to this point? That way, we'll be able to see where you've gone wrong with your current approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does the trick:

```js
$('.container h2').each(function() {    //for each h2
  $(this)
    .nextUntil('h2')                    //get siblings until next h2, or all next siblings if no more h2
    .addBack()                          //include current h2
    .wrapAll('<div class="xy"/>');      //wrap it
});

$('pre').text($('.container').html());  //show it!
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <ul></ul>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
        
<pre></pre>
```